# Silverlight Toolkit LineSeries Title Removal

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I am using the silverlight toolkit lineseries control and want to get rid of the title but I cannot find a way via Expression Blend or VS.  I have tried to change the TitleStyle and LegendStyle of the parenting chart but have found that obviously irrelevant.  Any tips would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to give an update for anyone who runs into something similar.

Setting your chart's LegendStyle to as below will prevent the LineSeries title from appearing.

```
<charting:Chart.Legend>
    <Style TargetType=”datavis:Legend”>
        <Setter Property=”Width” Value=”0″/>
        <Setter Property=”Height” Value=”0″/>
    </Style>
 </charting:Chart.Legend>
```